Solve primal problem $\min x_1+x_2+x_3$ subject to $x_1^2+x_2^2\leq x_3\leq1$
As mention in title. Solve

$$\min x_1+x_2+x_3$$ Subject to $$x_1^2+x_2^2\leq x_3\leq1$$

by solving dual problem.
My answer:
First, the objective function can be updated to $x_1+x_2+x_1^2+x_2^2$, and the new constrain is $x_1^2+x_2^2\leq1$
$$\begin{align*}
\phi(\mathbf{\mu})&=\min\{x_1+x_2+x_1^2+x_2^2+\mu(x_1^2+x_2^2-1)\}
\end{align*}$$
Let $l(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{\mu})=x_1+x_2+x_1^2+x_2^2+\mu(x_1^2+x_2^2-1)$ be the function we want to minimise.
$$\begin{cases}
l_{x_1}&=1+2x_1+\mu(2x_1)=0\\
l_{x_2}&=1+2x_2+\mu(2x_2)=0
\end{cases}\implies x_1^*=x_2^*=-\frac{1}{2\mu+2}$$
Moreover $l$ is convex, so $(x_1^*,x_2^*)$ is optimal solutiont to $l$.
So, $\phi(\mu)=-\frac{1}{2\mu+2}-\mu$
$$\begin{align*}
\phi'&=0\\
\implies \mu&=-1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-1\\
\implies \mu&=0\quad\text{since $\mu\geq0$}
\end{align*}$$
Hence, $x_1^*,x_2^*=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $x_3^*=\frac{1}{2}$. Hence minimum is $-\frac{1}{2}$
Can anyone please check if there are any errors in my updated solution?

You need to be careful when defining the dual problem. You are missing a few important parts of the dual problem. (1) You have a constraint that $\mu_i \geq 0$. (2) you have the constraint $1-\mu_1 + \mu_2 - \mu_3 = 0$. (3) you are trying to maximize $\phi(\mu)$.

Thanks, I updated my solution

$x_3$ is missing in your solution

I have $x_3^*$ as part of my conclusion. Do you mean that?
